# RuntimeError when inverting Mass matrix symbolically (Python): "The following environment does not have an entry for the variable q(7)"

Tags: python, drake

I'm running into an issue with inverting the Mass matrix that I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Numeric inversion works with no issue. And I am able to invert a simpler model I put together to test this (a cartpole URDF) symbolically. But it fails with the model I am interested in. I am running into the run-time error: `The following environment does not have an entry for the variable q(7)`. q(7) is the first symbolic variable that shows up in the mass matrix.

A small snippet of the mass matrix:

```py
array([[<Expression "((q(7) * m(2) * ( - (q(0) * ((2 * q(1)) / (pow(q(0), 2) + pow(q(1), 2) + pow(q(2),...
```

I took a look at the Drake documentation, and I see that this "Environment" class for symbolic is a C++ only class, so I am unable to inspect anything. Just wondering what might be going on here. I ran the same code with a simple inverted pendulum URDF I put together, and it works just fine.

```py
from pydrake.symbolic import inv
expr = inv(M) @ (tauG + B@u - Cv@v)
```

- Note #1: q(7) corresponds to a DOF associated with one of 3 actuators for my plant.
- Note #2: This is a floating base model with quaternion orientation, so nq=10, nv=9.

Interestingly, I also tried using sym_plant.CalcMassMatrix(sym_context), and this fails with an error `RuntimeError: The following environment does not have an entry for the variable m(3)`, so I went back to look at the old pendulum toy example, and that also now fails (but only with CalcMassMatrix) with a similar error: `RuntimeError: The following environment does not have an entry for the variable m(0)`

I am aware that explicit computation of the mass matrix should be avoided whenever possible, but for my application it is something I need to do (at least once).

Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks,
Drew Hamilton

Answer (score 0):

Drake uses Eigen to compute the inverse.  See the code [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/v1.20.0/bindings/pydrake/math_operators_pybind.h#L14-L37).

For small sizes up to 4x4, Eigen uses cofactors. This method works even for symbolic matrices.

For larger matrices, Eigen uses `PartialPivLU` which is not compatible with symbolic matrices -- pivoting can't work if we have symbolic variables instead of actual numbers to compare.  This explains the error message -- pivoting would require `q(7)` to have a manifest value.

No workaround immediately comes to mind (other than writing your own symbolic matrix inverse logic, somehow).

Answer (score 0):

`jwnimmer-tri`'s answer is excellent.  As for a work-around... needing to explicitly compute the mass matrix is ok.  Taking the inverse symbolically is what should generally be avoided.

Often times you *can* avoid taking that inverse by formulating your problem using the implicit dynamics form.  We offer [`CalcImplicitTimeDerivativesResidual`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#a2bb4c1e3572a8009863b5a342fcb5c49) to help support this workflow.  It works for `MultibodyPlant` (and diagrams that contain a `MultibodyPlant`).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I hesitate to ask, but is there any plan to offer Sympy output/support? I know the whole Drake ecosystem is pretty carefully constructed and based on bindings of Eigen, so that may be a naive question...

Comment: I've been meaning to write up the SymPy feature request issue for a few months now.  This was enough to get me to do it.  See [drake#20076](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20076).

Answer (score 0):

@jwnimmer-tri is working toward a SymPy feature in Drake, so I'll close this.

If you stumble on this thread please FIRST check to see if this feature has been added [drake#20076](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20076)

Barring that, you can try this to get a sympy expression in a pinch:

```py
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import re
from pydrake.symbolic import Expression, Variable, ExpressionKind
from pydrake import math
from sympy import init_printing
from sympy import nan

def _div(expr1, expr2):
    return expr1 / expr2

function_dict = {
    ExpressionKind.Abs.value:  sp.Abs,
    ExpressionKind.Acos.value: sp.acos,
    ExpressionKind.Add.value:  sp.Add,
    ExpressionKind.Asin.value: sp.asin,
    ExpressionKind.Atan.value: sp.atan,
    ExpressionKind.Atan2.value: sp.atan2,
    ExpressionKind.Ceil.value: sp.ceiling,
    ExpressionKind.Constant.value: sp.Float,
    ExpressionKind.Cos.value: sp.cos,
    ExpressionKind.Cosh.value: sp.cosh,
    ExpressionKind.Div.value: lambda val1, val2: sp.Mul(val1, 1/val2),
    ExpressionKind.Exp.value: sp.exp,
    ExpressionKind.Floor.value: sp.floor,
    ExpressionKind.Log.value: sp.log,
    ExpressionKind.Max.value: sp.Max,
    ExpressionKind.Min.value: sp.Min,
    ExpressionKind.Mul.value: sp.Mul,
    ExpressionKind.Pow.value: sp.Pow,
    ExpressionKind.Sin.value: sp.sin,
    ExpressionKind.Sinh.value: sp.sinh,
    ExpressionKind.Sqrt.value: sp.sqrt,
    ExpressionKind.Tan.value:  sp.tan,
    ExpressionKind.Tanh.value: sp.tanh
}

def ExtractVarName(VarElement):
    return re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}', VarElement.GetVariables().to_string())[0]

def decompose(e : Expression):
    
    kind = e.get_kind()
    if (kind.value != ExpressionKind.Var.value):
        operator = function_dict[kind.value]
    else:
        _var = ExtractVarName(e)
        return sp.Symbol(_var)
    
    sp_exprs = []
    _, args = e.Unapply()
    for element in args:
        
        # This should also catch NaN:
        if isinstance(element, float):   # Leading element of expression is often bare float64 (not Constant?)
            _val = sp.Float(element)
            sp_exprs.append(_val)
        elif isinstance(element, int):
            _val = sp.Int(element)
            sp_exprs.append(_val)            
        else:
            kind = element.get_kind()
            match kind.value:
                case ExpressionKind.Var.value:
                    _var = ExtractVarName(element) 
                    sp_exprs.append(sp.Symbol(_var))
                case _:
                    sp_exprs.append(decompose(element))
    
    return operator(*sp_exprs)
```

and this to convert back to pydrake.symbolic. Note you want to pass in a dict with the symbolic variables, so you get back a clean pydrake expression (see example at very end).

```py
from sympy import Symbol, Function
from pydrake.symbolic import Variable, Expression
from pydrake import math
from functools import reduce
from pydrake.symbolic import ExtractVariablesFromExpression


# Note div is just mul(val1, 1/val2), there's no sympy div obj
# sqrt is just x**(1/2), so comes in as pow

drake_function_dict = {
    sp.Abs: math.abs,    
    sp.acos: math.acos,    
    sp.core.add.Add: lambda *args: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, args),    
    sp.asin: math.asin,
    sp.atan: math.atan,
    sp.atan2: math.atan2,
    sp.ceiling: math.ceil,
    sp.Float: lambda val: Expression(val),
    sp.cos: math.cos,
    sp.cosh: math.cosh,    
    sp.exp: math.exp,
    sp.floor: math.floor,
    sp.log: math.log,
    sp.Max: math.max,
    sp.Min: math.min,
    sp.core.mul.Mul: lambda *args: reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, args), 
    sp.Pow: math.pow,    
    sp.sin: math.sin,
    sp.sinh: math.sinh,
    sp.tan: math.tan,
    sp.tanh: math.tanh,
    sp.Symbol: Variable
}

def recompose(e, variable_dict):
    
    operator = 0
    
    if not e.is_number and type(e) != sp.core.symbol.Symbol:
        operator = drake_function_dict[type(e)]
    elif e.is_number:
        return Expression(e.evalf())
    if type(e) == sp.core.symbol.Symbol:
        #return Variable(str(e))
        return variable_dict[str(e)]
    
    drake_exprs = []
    args = e.args

    for element in args:
        
        # This should also catch NaN:
        if type(element) == sp.core.symbol.Symbol:
            #drake_exprs.append(Variable(str(element)))  
            drake_exprs.append(variable_dict[str(element)])  
        elif element.is_number:
            drake_exprs.append(Expression(element.evalf()))         
        else:
            drake_exprs.append(recompose(element, variable_dict))
    
    return operator(*drake_exprs)
```

You can test all this with this slightly messy bit of code. This evaluates the original symbolic expression numerically, as well as the sympy expression, and the conversion back to pydrake to make sure they agree to machine precision. You can also inspect the expressions in LaTeX in a notebook. They are mathematically identical, though they may look slightly different:

```py
x = Variable("x")
y = Variable("y")

# Complicated compound expression:
x = Variable("x")
y = Variable("y")
compound_expr = (
    (x/y) / (Expression(1.0) + math.cos(x) + x*y + math.exp(math.sin(2+x*y)) + 
    math.ceil(math.log(math.exp(y**2))))
)

varlist, _ = ExtractVariablesFromExpression(compound_expr)
variable_dict = {variable.get_name(): variable for variable in varlist}
variable_dict

print("VARDICT: ", variable_dict)

print(compound_expr)
print(".vs.")
sp_expr = sp.simplify(decompose(compound_expr))
display(sp_expr)
print("\nand back:")
sp_expr2 = recompose(sp_expr, variable_dict)
print(sp_expr2)
print("Original Vars?: ", sp_expr2.GetVariables())


func = sp.lambdify((x, y), sp_expr, 'numpy')
func2 = sp.lambdify((x, y), sp_expr2, 'numpy')

assert np.isclose( func(0.32, 3.2), compound_expr.Evaluate({x:0.32, y:3.2}))
print("\nOriginal expression evaluates same as sympy expression: ", func(0.32, 3.2))

assert np.isclose( func2(0.32, 3.2), compound_expr.Evaluate({x:0.32, y:3.2}))
print("\nAnd final expression evaluates same as original expression: ", func2(0.32, 3.2))

varlist, _ = ExtractVariablesFromExpression(compound_expr)
varlist2, _ = ExtractVariablesFromExpression(recomposed)

for v1, v2 in zip(varlist, varlist2):
    assert(v1.get_id() == v1.get_id())

print("\nVariables match orginal drake expression.")
```

Will delete this answer when the feature is complete.